# What are 'Potential Leaks' in Xcode, and can they be ignored?

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks

I am using the "analyse" menu option from within Xcode 4.2 and I have three "potential leaks". What is a "potential leak"??

When I build and run the app, everything works fine. When I use the 'leaks' tool, none of these three parts of code are shown to leak. So can these 'potential leaks' just be ignored?

The three sections of code that contain 'potential leaks' are (note, these are not sequential blocks of code, but are on different files)...

First...

```
- (void)DoDomainCheck {
AppDelegate *dataCentre = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *queryStringFull = [queryStringFirst stringByAppendingString:dataCentre.DomainCheckData];
labeltocheck.text = dataCentre.DomainCheckData;

responseData = [NSMutableData new];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myurl.com/whois.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSData *requestData = [queryStringFull dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Second...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
cell.textLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"date"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];

[cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[cell.textLabel sizeToFit];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
}
```

Third...

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    [item setObject:currentImage forKey:@"media"];
    [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
    [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"];
    [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"];
    [stories addObject:[item copy]];
}
}
```

Can anyone see any obvious issues with these sections of code, or can I just ignore these 'potential' leaks?

Comment: A "potential leak" is a spot where the Static Analyzer has identified a violation of the standard memory management rules. However, it can't be 100% positive that this is a leak (it's possible to write unconventional code that violates the rules and still ends up balancing retains/releases, but that's pretty rare), but it's generally pretty good at identifying this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Analyzer click on the arrow indicators to see the path through the code that produces the potential leak.

Part 1:
for autoreleased responseData use:

```
responseData = [NSMutableData data];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

an `NSURLConnection` is allocated

Part 2: 
See the answer by @Bill Bransky

Part 3:

[stories addObject:[item copy]];

The `copy` is not necessary, it increases the reference count and `addObject` also increases the reference count. When the `stories` object is releases a release will be sent to each of it's items but there will still be an extra reference count from the `copy`.

About the `copy`, when writing code always know exactly why each statement and statement part is written. If in doubt research. Adding code without knowing exactly will create that "works by coincidence", is fragile and will probably cause problems later.

It would really help you to study Apple's memory management documents. Also strongly consider ARC.

In answer to your question, leaks don't cause crashes but do use memory and that can be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think something got copy/pasted wrong in part 1. You have your NSURLConnection alloc/init. Doesn't say what you are init'ing that into. But whatever it is, it should be released when done.

Part 2, need to set your cell to be autoreleased. Will fix your potential leak there.

Part 3, you are adding a retain item with your [item copy]. This will cause item to leak. May need to rethink how you have that set up.

Answer (score 0):

That line:

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

as the last line before the end of a method body looks like a leak to me - you allocate an object with an "init" method, which by convention returns a retained object, without keeping a reference to the object in an ivar.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear those potential leaks.Focus on the allocation of objects and deallocation .